# Realistic Collision Response in DirectX 3D Ball vs Wall

Tags: c++, 3d, directx, collision-detection, game-physics

**Problem**
The problem I am faced with is the response from the collision of 2 3D objects by AABB collision. Now I have searched high and low throughout the internet for an explanation or example of how this is implemented but to no avail. Before I explain the problem please may I ask that no one directs me to a third party physics library to do this I would like to write the code from scratch.

On colliding the ball with the brick my aim is to have the ball reduce its velocity and momentum on contact with the brick and have the brick shoot off in the direction of the balls velocity etc. That part is easy and I understand where I am going with that. The hard part is how will I make the brick **realistically** look like something has hit it. When the ball hits the brick the brick should rotate and flip like a real collision.

The end goal here is to have a brick wall and the ball collides with that and the bricks fly off and then fall down in a realistic way rotating as they would.

The key here is the **rotation** on impact. Here is a short video of what I have so far.

[image]

If you cannot see the image the link is: https://giphy.com/gifs/l49JKTW3QHTuMaXZu

**Code**

*Collision Between Ball and Brick*

```
bool CollideBoxes(BoundingBox &a, BoundingBox &b) {
    float AxMax = a.x + (a.width / 2);
    float AxMin = a.x - (a.width / 2);
    float AyMax = a.y + (a.depth / 2);
    float AyMin = a.y - (a.depth / 2);
    float AzMax = a.z + (a.height / 2);
    float AzMin = a.z - (a.height / 2);

    float BxMax = b.x + (b.width / 2);
    float BxMin = b.x - (b.width / 2);
    float ByMax = b.y + (b.depth / 2);
    float ByMin = b.y - (b.depth / 2);
    float BzMax = b.z + (b.height / 2);
    float BzMin = b.z - (b.height / 2);
    bool condition = false;
    if (AxMin < BxMax && AxMax > BxMin) {
        condition = true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
    if (AyMin < ByMax && AyMax > ByMin) {
        condition = true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
    if (AzMin < BzMax && AzMax > BzMin) {
        condition = true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

    return condition;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I couldn't have a look at the video. May be, it's broken but I bet it's blocked due to my companies security policy. For simulation of the "tumbling" brick, I would consider to (re-)search about [Momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum) and [Torque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque). (I wouldn't have mentioned it but I missed these terms in your question, and I believe these are the key words concerning your problem.)

Comment: If you cant see the image here is the link: https://media.giphy.com/media/l49JKTW3QHTuMaXZu/giphy.gif

Comment: Yepp. It's as I already assumed: If I click on your link all I get is a gray window telling me "Diese Verbindung is nicht sicher" (This connection is not safe.) Don't consider this anymore - I'm used to. Btw. I cannot tell you more about this as I'm rather at beginners level concerning physics/mechanics. (I just know who of my team to ask if necessary...) :-)

Comment: Search for "rigid-body physics" on the internet. Plenty of tutorials to cover rotational dynamics (the equation of motion is slightly more complicated than the linear case). Also, you should add the `game-physics` tag.